# Pandas not recognizing numeric value and ljust at the same time

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am new to Python and ran into bit of a stand-still with my process.

What it does: Reads in a CSV file, does some rearranging, outputs new file with re-arranged columns and values.

The problem: My output CSV has to be in a specific format so it can be consumed properly.. this included quotes around all values (including the header) and having padded values (with spaces).

I am using PANDAS to do all computations
The important logic is here:

```
 df['QUANTITY1'] = df['QUANTITY1'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.ljust(7)).astype(object)
 df['QUANTITY2'] = df['QUANTITY2'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.ljust(7)).astype(object)
```

These quantity values are float numbers, so in order to apply the space padding (ljust), I have to convert it to a string.

When I go to output the csv and write it, I am using something like this:

```
df.to_csv(writeFileTo, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, columns=['STATUS'.ljust(20),'TIME'.ljust(25), 'QUANTITY1', 'QUANTITY1'])
```

The output works great, but the problem is the QUANTITY1 and QUANTITY2 columns contain output with quotes (i think this is becuase csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC views that column as string, not numeric).

So... I decide to change the two columns back to floats so that it won't have quotes in the output. Problem number 2: when i change the values to float, they don't preserve the spacing (ljust). What do I do to keep the spacing but also have pandas not output quotes?!

TLDR; I need to have ljust or rjust float numbers in pandas csv output

Comment: share some sample data for us to work on !

Comment: It seems like you want a fixed width text file instead? Also can you show what `df` looks like?

Comment: Would something like this work? `df.to_csv(writeFileTo, float_format=":7.3f")`. This says that the output should be  shown as floats of 7 digits limited to 3 decimal places.

Comment: Unfortunately, it says "not all arguments converted during string formatting" when i add that float_format